Using proxy with keycloak and spring boot 3
With spring security Oauth2, I’m currently using maven dependancy :
<dependency
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

Next, my Oauth2Client SecurityFilterChain configuration looks like :
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
       .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users*"))
       .hasRole("user")
       .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"))
       .permitAll()
       .anyRequest()
       .authenticated());
    http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
       .logout(logout -> logout.addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler).logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
    return http.build();
}

And my property file :
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=login-app
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://mykeycloakurl:8080/realms/myrealm
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username

At the startup, My server will ping the keycloak server to get some informations on http//mykeycloakurl:8080/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration.
My keycloak must be ping by using a specific proxy.
Definitivly, my question is :
How to override the default http client used by OauthClient configuration, to use a proxy.
—-
Please, I don’t work configure an httpProxy on the JVM like below :
-Dhttp.proxyHost=123.123.123 -Dhttp.proxyPort=1010
